# Unable to get text using Xpath although using /text() already

Tags: python, xpath

I'm trying to scrape data from [here](https://www.racenet.com.au/horse-racing-results/happy-valley/2016-11-16) using XPath and although I'm using inspect to copy the path and adding /text() to the end an empty list is being returned instead of `["Class 5"]` for the text in between the last span tags.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

sample_page = requests.get("https://www.racenet.com.au/horse-racing-results/happy-valley/2016-11-16")
tree = html.fromstring(sample_page.content)
r1class = tree.xpath('//*[@id="resultsListContainer"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/span[1]/text()')

print(r1class)
```

The element that I'm targeting is the Class for race 1 (Class 5), and the structure matches the XPath that I'm using.

Comment: //*[@id="resultsListContainer"]/div[3]/table//tr[1]/td/span[1]/text()

Comment: still getting nothing

Comment: Verification using Firebug proves there is nothing wrong with your XPath expression, must be something else.

Comment: Thanks Bouke, any ideas where to start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should do the job, i.e. it works when using other sites with a matching XPath expression. The *racenet* site doesn't deliver valid HTML, which might very probably be the reason your code fails. This can be verified by using the W3C online validator: https://validator.w3.org

```
import lxml.html

html = lxml.html.parse('https://www.racenet.com.au/horse-racing-results/happy-valley/2016-11-16')
r1class = html.xpath('//*[@id="resultsListContainer"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/span[1]/text()')[0]
print(r1class)
```

Comment: A workaround may be to read the HTML document using the *requests* library, correct the HTML declaration and parse the corrected HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started.

```
import requests
from lxml.etree import HTML

sample_page = requests.get("https://www.racenet.com.au/horse-racing-results/happy-valley/2016-11-16").content
tree = HTML(sample_page)
races = tree.xpath('//table[@class="tblLatestHorseResults"]')
for race in races:
    rows = race.xpath('.//tr')
    for row in rows:
        row_text_as_list = [i.xpath('string()').replace(u'\xa0', u'') for i in row.xpath('.//td') if i is not None]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression doesn't match anything, because the HTML page you are trying to scrape is seriously broken. FF (or any other web browser) fixes the page on the go, before displaying it. This results in HTML tags being added, which are not present in the original document.

The following code contains an XPath expression, which will most likely point you in the right direction.

```
import requests
from lxml import html, etree
sample_page = requests.get("https://www.racenet.com.au/horse-racing-results/happy-valley/2016-11-16")
tree = html.fromstring(sample_page.content)
nodes = tree.xpath("//*[@id='resultsListContainer']/div/table[@class='tblLatestHorseResults']/tr[@class='raceDetails']/td/span[1]")
for node in nodes:
    print etree.tostring(node)
```

When executed, this prints the following:

```
$ python test.py
<span class="bold">Class 5</span> Track: 
<span class="bold">Class 4</span> Track: 
<span class="bold">Class 4</span> Track: 
<span class="bold">Class 4</span> Track: 
<span class="bold">Class 4</span> Track: 
<span class="bold">Class 3</span> Track: 
<span class="bold">Class 2</span> Track: 
<span class="bold">Class 3</span> Track:
```

Tip: whenever you are trying to scrape a web page, and things just don't work as expected, download and save the HTML to a file. In this case, e.g.:

```
f = open("test.xml", 'w')
f.write(sample_page.content)
```

Then have a look at the saved HTML. This gives you an idea of how the DOM will look like.